# How to use typespecs and Dialyzer with Behaviours?

Tags: elixir

In Elixir how can I document that a function will return a module that implements a specific behaviour?

To use a trivial example, say I have created a `GreeterBehaviour` behaviour that is implemented by two modules:

```
defmodule GreeterBehaviour do
  @callback say_hello(String.t) :: String.t
end

defmodule FormalGreeter do
  @behaviour GreeterBehaviour

  def say_hello(name) do
    "Good day to you #{name}"
  end
end

defmodule CasualGreeter do
  @behaviour GreeterBehaviour

  def say_hello(name) do
    "Hey #{name}"
  end
end
```

I then want to easily swap out either of those implementations by retrieving the Greeter via a function:

```
defmodule MyApp do
  def main do
    greeter().say_hello("Pete") |> IO.puts
  end

  @spec greeter() :: GreeterBehaviour # This doesn't work with dialyzer
  def greeter do
    FormalGreeter # Can easily be swapped to CasualGreeter
  end
end
```

Dialyzer will successfully check that both `CasualGreeter` and `FormalGreeter` correctly implement the `GreeterBehaviour` behaviour. However, how can I define a typespec so that Dialyzer will check that `greeter/0` returns a module that does in fact implement `GreeterBehaviour`?

Using `@spec greeter() :: GreeterBehaviour` doesn't work as Dialyzer will throw a warning:

```
lib/my_app.ex:19: Invalid type specification for function 'Elixir.MyApp':greeter/0. The success typing is () -> 'Elixir.FormalGreeter'
```

Comment: That is a good question and I am not sure if it's possible to specify behaviour in the typespec, I think you can just put this as the spec `@spec greeter() :: FormalGreeter` so that dialyzer will know what module exactly you are returning ( in your case it will know anyway, even without the spec at all ) and then maybe it could check that you are calling functions on the module that dont exist.

Comment: AFAICT this is not currently possible; I wish it was.

Comment: vote for this feature as well

Comment: Not sure about typespecs, but I tend to do this using configuration (`config :my_app, greeter_module: FormalGreeter`)

Comment: @DerekKraan I think that's a motivating example for why this would be nice, e.g. to catch if you configure the wrong module in a config file.

Answer (score 1):

In your behaviour you could define a type for `say_hello`:

```
@type f :: (String.t() -> String.t())
```

Your `greeter` function could return a module + function: `&module.say_hello/1`

And the spec would be:

```
@spec greeter() :: GreeterBehaviour.f()
```

```
defmodule GreeterBehaviour do
  @type f :: (String.t() -> String.t())
  @callback say_hello(String.t()) :: String.t()
end

defmodule FormalGreeter do
  @behaviour GreeterBehaviour

  def say_hello(name) do
    "Good day to you #{name}"
  end
end

defmodule CasualGreeter do
  @behaviour GreeterBehaviour

  def say_hello(name) do
    "Hey #{name}"
  end
end

defmodule MyApp do
  def main do
    greeter().("Pete") |> IO.puts()
  end

  # This will work with dialyzer
  @spec greeter() :: GreeterBehaviour.f()
  def greeter do
    # Can easily be swapped to CasualGreeter
    &FormalGreeter.say_hello/1
  end
end
```